# Anaphase Microtubule Disassembly

Tags: cell

Centromeres move toward the poles as the microtubules that connect them shorten. This shortening is due to the removal of tubulin subunits from the kinetochore ends of the microtubules.

I'm confused as to how the centromeres can be pulled closer to their respective poles while tubulin subunits are being removed. To me, this is similar to pulling an object by a rope while simultaneously cutting pieces of the rope out. How do the centromeres remain connected to the spindles while tubulin subunits are being removed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the microtubules shorten. The disassembly of tubulin (dynamic catastrophe) happens from its + end which in this case is protected by the kinetochore proteins. The separation of chromatids, I *guess*, happens via a dynein (and in some cases kinesin) mediated movement.

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetochore) on kinetochore is quite detailed and you can have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant that the length of the microtubule spindle fibers shorten due to the removal of tubulin subunits.

Comment: yes.. but it does not happen thay way as I can recall. the removal of tubulin subunits happens from the + end which is now protected.

Comment: How exactly do the kinetochore proteins protect the + end?

Comment: In different species it's different - in some it's packman like ie disassembly from the + end but in some the microtubules are reeled in (from the centriole end)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a very long time ago, but for future viewers, below is a useful snapshot taken from my Campbell's Biology Textbook. As you can see, the motor proteins are not located at the very "tip" of the microtubule, so they are still able to carry the chromosome to the pole while the tubulin subunits disassemble on the kinetochore end. For more about motor proteins, go [here](http://www.tocris.com/pharmacologicalBrowser.php?ItemId=187904#.VpUoSFJRK8A), to YouTube, or wikipedia.

[image]